# How describe Hbase column family?

Tags: hbase

I am looking for a command which describes the columnfamily inside the table from the HBase Shell. I could not get any command to try this.

Answer (score 26, accepted):

If you use the `describe` command from the `hbase shell`
you'll get the information for each column family.
Currently, there is no way to filter on a single family.

Example:

```
hbase(main):003:0> describe 'TABLE_NAME'
 'TABLE_NAME',
 {NAME => 'FAMILY_NAME',
  DATA_BLOCK_ENCODING => 'NONE',
  BLOOMFILTER => 'ROW',
  REPLICATION_ true                                          
  SCOPE => '0',
  VERSIONS => '1',
  COMPRESSION => 'NONE',
  MIN_VERSIONS => '0', TTL => '2147483647',
  KEEP_DELETED_CELLS => 'false',
  BLOCKSIZE => '65536',
  IN_MEMORY => 'false',
  BLOCKCACHE => 'true'
 }
```

Answer (score 3):

There is no command to describe the Hbase column family (which can display the column qualifiers), but I  used Hue Hbase Browser, it has a smartview, which can display column qualifiers of a column family.

(It can not show all the column qualifiers of column family( like describe), but it can show a record with all the column qualifiers, which is helpful for me to understand CF) (Something is better than nothing).

You can refer this link for more information:  http://gethue.com/the-web-ui-for-hbase-hbase-browser/.

**NOTE:** *Here is a sample page screenshot, showing column qualifiers of a Column Family ("p")*
[image]

If this is not helpful, you can write a Happy Script to display all the column qualifiers of a given Column Family, or you can use this [API](https://hbase.apache.org/0.94/apidocs/org/apache/hadoop/hbase/client/Result.html#getFamilyMap(byte[])).

> getFamilyMap public NavigableMap getFamilyMap(byte[]
>   family)
>
> Map of qualifiers to values. Returns a Map of the form:
>   Map
>
> Parameters:
>
> family - column family to get
>
> Returns: map of qualifiers to values

#### UPDATE #1

Recently I wrote a Java program to display the column family and column qualifiers of a hbase table. Remember, this program will do a full table scan and analyze every cell, to get the qualifier names.Might take very longer for larger tables.

Here is the [link for the program](http://skanandkumar.blogspot.com/2016/08/how-to-describe-hbase-table-with-column.html).

Comment: The screenshow showing the CF "p" was very helpful for me. Thx.

Answer (score 0):

I found this answer and added some modifications to it:

```
it list all column family for each Cqualifier
  echo "scan 'yourTable', {'LIMIT' => 1} " | $HBASE_HOME/bin/hbase shell | awk -F'=' '{print $2}' | awk -F ':' '{print $1}'|awk -F ',' '{print $1}'
```