# HBase shell describing particular column

Tags: hbase

In HBase shell, I have a HBase table names SENSOR

has two column families

VALUE

I want to describe that column family not the whole table . what command I should write?

Comment: what do you mean by describe a single columnfamily?. AFAIK there is no column describe command

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How describe Hbase column family?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21473087/how-describe-hbase-column-family)